# git: moving branch head

Tags: git

I have two git branches, "A" and "B", and commits numbered 1 thru 8.  My history looks like this

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4[A] -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8[B]
```

I want to change it so my history looks like this:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6[A] -> 7 -> 8[B]
```

That is, I want to move the head of branch A from commit 4 to commit 6.

What commands do I use to do this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can run:

```
git branch -f A 6
```

Comment: This works in this situation because A actually contains nothing; it just points to the branchpoint and so we move the pointer elsewhere without losing anything. Suppose A had some commits? Then you have to do a `git rebase` to carry over the commits. That is more general and should handle this "empty branch" trivial case too.

Comment: @Kaz, git has lightweight branches, so they never "contain" anything.  They are just a moving sticky note attached to a commit.  My answer is for this scenario, a linear branch history.  If it wasn't linear, I would look at what the OP actually wanted and come up with a solution.

Comment: You could say that about CVS too then. A branch doesn't contain anything. It's just a branch tag ("sticky note") denoting a branch number like 1.2.0.2. Does CVS have light-weight branching? :)

Comment: i couldn't do this while on branch A, so i went with @ralphtheninja's answer.

Comment: @Jayen You can still use Matthew's solution, you just have to checkout any other branch first. If A is your only branch, just do `git checkout -b temp`; `git branch -f A 6`; `git checkout A`.

Comment: After doing this to move an old branch to the current HEAD, I added another commit and HEAD diverged from the branch (the branch stayed behind).  Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 17):

```
git checkout A
git reset --hard 6
```

Comment: This works, but is the "hard way".  The reason it works is that if you are "on a branch" (in git terms), `git reset --hard <rev>` moves the branch for you.  But `git branch -f <name> <rev>` re-points the branch in one step.  There is one limitation: `git branch -f` won't let you move your current branch.  So if you're already "on branch A" (as shown by `git branch` output) you need to use this `git reset --hard` method.  (Or get off branch A, but that's getting silly. :-) )

Answer (score 10):

This is a special case of rebase, just that the branch is empty:

```
git checkout A
git rebase B
```

`rebase` is more general; it handles this case also:

Before:

```
                  A1 -> A2 -> [A]
                /
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4  -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8[B]
```

After:

```
                                      A1' -> A2' -> [A]
                                     /
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4  -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8[B]
```

A1' and A2' are merged to account for the delta between 4 and 8 on the parent branch.

Git rebase handles this trivial case without a hassle. I created a repo with two commits on `master` and a branch `br` pointing to the first commit.

```
$ git checkout br
Switched to branch 'br'
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded br to master.
```

Poof, done. The log now shows the branch pointing to the second commit.

We can also achieve this "After": [thanks to M. Flaschen for pointing out this was missing]:

```
                            A1'' -> A2'' -> [A]
                           /
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4  -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8[B]
```

Instead of rebasing to the branch B, we would name the specific commit 6, e.g.

```
git checkout A
git rebase 6   # rather than rebase B
```

When there are no A1 and A2 commits, this reduces to the original question: moving the [A] pointer from 4 to 6.

Comment: The before case does not match the question.  In the question, no commits are only on A.

Comment: The before case is a generalization of the question. A1 and A2 don't exist. An empty list is a list.

Comment: Your after case  also doesn't match.  [A] is pointing to 8, rather than 6.  Also, I'm not sure this generalization helps answer the original question.

Comment: `git rebase <commit>` works just fine, and by doing that you can move the branch from [4] to [6]`. I will update my response. Whoever modded this down, go stuff yourself. This is the right way to do it using the high level user interface for branch hopping.